# Error in skin config file with Mplayer

Tags: mplayer

Trying to watch a VOB file. Installed MPlayer but it isn't opening. I am getting an error message saying 'Fatal Error':

*Error in skin config file at line 6: PNG read error in usr/share/mplayer/skins/default/main*

What does this mean

Comment: I'm still getting this error when running `gmplayer` (mplayer-gui 2:1.3.0-8build4) in ubuntu 19.10 (eoan). As a work-around, I can run `mplayer` from the command-line, or use smplayer (a different gui wrapper around mplayer).

Comment: @michael - Please see answer I just posted. It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

The problem seems to be with the outdated Ubuntu skins package:

```
mplayer-skins
```

The PNGs are not in the correct format.

The Ubuntu packages `mplayer` and `mplayer-gui` are quite old.

Ubuntu has the outdated skin package.

I got it fixed with the following command:

```
cd /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default; for FILE in *.png; do sudo convert $FILE -define png:format=png24 $FILE; done
```

Comment: for FILE in *.png; do sudo convert $FILE -define png:format=png24 $FILE; done

solved the problem thank  you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the skins.
Go to [Beyond Linux' page about mplayer](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/mplayer.html).
Scroll down to "Skins" and download `Clearlooks-1.9.tar.bz2`. This was the latest version when I checked, on 2017-11-27.

Then, scroll down to "Skin Installation" and follow the instructions, but first delete `/usr/share/mplayer/skins/default` (which was a link to `clearplayer`). The instructions create a link to `Clearlooks`, the new skin directory.

Answer (score 1):

http://muhdzamri.blogspot.com/2016/01/mplayer-gui-error-error-in-skin-config.html
this helped me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/mplay-skins
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
#sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:mc3man/mplay-skins # You can remove the repository this way again.
```

The error with skin disappered but a new error appeared:
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

It seems that this second bug is not related to the skin's bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvdpau/+bug/1300215

So as I see it, I have to return to GNOME-mplayer :-((

Well, I do not know whether this has helped you...

Answer (score 1):

May be it is too late to share the solution/answer here.
I tried below command to install the mplayer and it worked absolutely fine for me.

```
sudo apt install mplayer mplayer-gui
```

May be it will help guys who might come here in future looing for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

*tl;dr* still broken

I am also seeing

```
$ gmplayer
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-7 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
...
Error in skin config file at line 6: PNG read error in /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default/main
Config file processing error with skin 'default'

Exiting... (Fatal error)
```

Using

```
$ dpkg -s mplayer-gui | grep '^Version:'
Version: 2:1.3.0-7build2

$ dpkg -s mplayer-skins | grep '^Version:'
Version: 3.2
```

---

Relates to Launchpad bugs

- [1218510](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mplayer/+bug/1218510) *Fails to open due to: PNG read error in /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default/main*
- [1340454](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mplayer/+bug/1340454) *Error in skin config file*
- [1575818](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mplayer/+bug/1575818) *mplayer crashes on start*
- [1693410](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mplayer/+bug/1693410) *gmplayer is broken*

According to [bug 1218510 comment #32](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mplayer/+bug/1218510/comments/32),

> This bug was fixed in the package mplayer-skins - 3.2build1
>
> mplayer-skins (3.2build1) cosmic; urgency=medium

Then in [comment #33](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mplayer/+bug/1218510/comments/33)

> The new package http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/m/mplayer-skins/mplayer-skins_3.2build1_all.deb still doesn't work

Check your version of `mplayer-skins` package with command
 `dpkg -s mplayer-skins`.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me, overcoming all the "still broken" mentions.
(*files in the repo are actually broken*).
Taken from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2381486&p=13726035#post13726035).

1. Get the `deb` package with the right `png`s

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mplay-skins/+files/mplayer-skins_3.2.1~xenial_all.deb
```

2. Install it.

```
gdebi mplayer-skins_3.2.1~xenial_all.deb
```

Others would add the `ppa`. It should work as well.

In addition, I would change the default skin.
`Blue` is nicer, and it removes the warning messages stemming from file `/usr/share/mplayer/skins/clearplayer/skin`

```
$ cd ~/.mplayer
$ mkdir skins
$ ln -s /usr/share/mplayer/skins/Blue default
```

(this overrides the soft link `/usr/share/mplayer/skins/default -> /usr/share/mplayer/skins/clearplayer`).
I do not know yet how to change the font size for the skin, if possible at all.