# How to set non-GUI mplayer as the default video application in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: video, mplayer

This question has been asked already [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548503/how-to-set-mplayer-as-the-default-video-application-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts), but not answered. That is why I am asking this question again...

I want `mp4` video files associated with the **Non-GUI** version of mplayer!

The video files are already associated with mplayer, but when I double-click the files from within Nautilus, I get an error:

```
Error in skin config file at line 6: PNG read error in /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default/main
```

and because I do not care at all about 'skins', I want to skin-less 'version' of mplayer to open the video file. Because on the command line there is no problem to open the video file

```
mplayer video.mp4
```

But how can I have the video file open with the command-line 'version' (skinless, NON GUI) of mplayer?

Comment: Your linked question looks like it has been answered.  I have tested it in 18.04 and it works fine.  In the link it shows both parts to the answer.  First part is in the question and the second part is in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Terrance Then I do not understand the answer. I created a new file named `~/.local/share/applications/mp.desktop` with the content as shown in the question, and did a right-click to associate mplayer with that kind of file. `mplayer` is already selected as the default type for that kind of file. 
And when I double click on the file the GUI version of mplayer started. I want the command-line/headless/NON-GUI version of mplayer. Maybe you misunderstood my question?

Comment: Best to remove the `mplayer-gui` first then.  `sudo apt remove --autoremove mplayer-gui`  Also, in the linked question and answer, really all you should have to do is log out and back in then the non-GUI mplayer should be now the default associated player for the files.  According to the linked question and answer it should now be showing exactly as `MPlayer (FullScreen)` but you can change that in the `mp.desktop` file.

Comment: related (to the underlying error, that is): https://askubuntu.com/questions/943068/error-in-skin-config-file-with-mplayer